# Xpost using libcurl in C++

Tags: c++, post, libcurl

I'm currently using curl in bash and have something like this:

```
cat req
{ "index" : { "_index": "override", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
curl -XPOST  localhost:80/testing/_bulk --data-binary @req
```

However I'm now building a c++ program and I'm trying to achieve the same thing. I can't seem to find any c++ examples to do "xpost" but I have found code which claims to do post:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html

Is this the right approach or am I barking up the wrong tree again? If I am, can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction please.

Comment: Th `-X` part is just asking for the method so `-X POST` is a simple `POST`

Comment: So it's the same as ```-X post```?

Comment: Yes it seems the space between the switch `-X` and its argument (`POST` or `GET` or `HEAD` etc...) is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "xpost", check the simplepost example http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html